# PCB8711 Rev. A of Sender 5000 solid-state AM transmitter: schematic symbol

Tags: identification, transmitter, symbol, amplitude-modulation

I wonder what the symbol encircled below means, because we're repairing an AM transmitter.

[image: PCB8711 Rev. A of Sender 5000 Solid State AM Transmitter schematic]

I think the real-life version of that schematic looks like this:

[image: PCB8711 Rev. A of Sender 5000 Solid State AM Transmitter schematic real life]

I really wonder what the symbol encircled above meant. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

> But I see two groups of 7 contact connector from each side of real life PCB8711 board while in the schematic it only shows one group of 7 contact connector. Why?

[image]

The PCB contains two instances of your circuit. The symmetry is fairly obvious.

1. The lower instance.
2. The upper instance.
3. A cutting line if only one instance is required.
4. and 5. Mounting holes for half-board stand-offs.

Answer (score 2):

> *I really wonder what the symbol encircled above meant.*

It symbolizes a connection point for the wires leaving your PCB.

Comment: oooh...i see...the symbol means they're just connectors from the PCB8711 board to something external. But I see two groups of 7 contact connector from each side of real life PCB8711 board while in the schematic it only shows one group of 7 contact connector. Why?

Comment: Two circuits on one PCB by the looks of it. If you'd shown the schematic description box it might have given a clue or, maybe there is a sheet 2 diagram that shows a similar circuit.

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the (probably female) connection points of a 7-contact connector used for connecting the PCB to something external.

From the looks of it, the (symmetrical) PCB assembly implements the schematic twice, which is why there are two connectors on the PCB.

Comment: oooh...i see...the symbol means they're just connectors from the PCB8711 board to something external. But I see two groups of 7 contact connector from each side of real life PCB8711 board while in the schematic it only shows one group of 7 contact connector. Why?

Comment: @Shobeh: I don't know, but from the looks of it, the physical PCB assembly implements the schematic twice.